# Can I pause Cucumber/Selenium JS execution while it waits for longer time?

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I have a scenario like this

```
Scenario: Long Wait
Given I Make some changes on webpage
When I wait at least 10 mins for changes to take effect
Then I can see the changes took effect
```

The step 2 is of course solvable by waiting 10 minutes, but those are 10 minutes I'd rather spend testing other scenarios which don't interfere with the changes made.

Is there a way to run specific scenarios in the 10 min gap, and then resume the original scenario? Something like

1. Execute the `Long Wait` scenario
2. Once it gets to step 2, pause this scenario
3. Run scenarios from the non-interfering pool
4. Wait until 10 minutes are up
5. Finish the non-interfering scenario that is currently running
6. Resume the original `Long Wait` scenario